# When to use TDD instead BDD and vice versa

Tags: java, testing, tdd, bdd

I am newbie to testing and I came across TDD and BDD approaches. But I am confused of it. I don't know when is better choice to use TDD instead BDD and vice versa. I came across some articles but they are more about differences...

I have some tips but not sure about their validity.

**1)**
If I imagine that I would like to implement well known `java.lang.List` then what approach to use? In this case it seems to me that TDD is better choice... Because it is some part of API/library and only programmer can use it, not a user. Although I can imagine that I could use BDD too, as:

**Story**: `Programmer adds an element to the list`

**Narrative** could be something like: `As a programmer I want to add an element to the list [so that ...]`

**Scenario 1**: `Adding null to the list` + given, when, then

**Scenario 2**: `Adding valid element to the list` + given, when, then

**Scenario 3**: ...

**2)**
But if I imagine that I would like to implement some GUI then it seems to me that BDD is better choice... Because it is something what a user can control (click on the button, fill the fields, etc...). TDD in this case does not seem to me as a good choice...

Next, can I mix them together? I read that BDD *includes* TDD in fact but in this case I mean wheter it is OK to use BOTH approaches in the project (e.g.: TDD for API and BDD for GUI) or I should choose only one approach.

Also, I really appreciate if you post here some links what helped to you to understand better testing in general...

You could post some guide/clues what you use for making decision...

Answer (score 4):

TDD and BDD are used for different purposes, so they definetely can be used together. BDD makes sure the user stories provided by the product owner/business analyst work and TDD makes sure the code (can be numerous classes) needed to make the BDD tests work is of high quality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And what's the step by step for use them together? Should I firstly write a behaviour tests and then tests for methods (add(), remove(), ...)? Or firstly tests for methods, then behaviour tests or other way?

Comment: First a BDD test, then unit tests while doing TDD. Therefore, if you are new to BDD and TDD I suggest starting with TDD and getting experience how to write unit tests.

Comment: Ok, also, if you read some interesting article/s and you have link to it, could post it here please? Thanks...

Comment: Start with books rather than articles, e.g. "Test Driven Development: By Example" by Kent Beck, "BDD in Action: Behavior-driven development for the whole software lifecycle", "Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests"